How many ways can a child take eleven pieces of candy from four types if the child does not take exactly two pieces of any type?
I solved this problem for an assignment and my solution was (using the principle of inclusion exclusion):
$$ N(U) - N(A \cup B \cup C \cup D)  = {4+11-1 \choose 11} - \left[ 4 {3+9-1 \choose 9} - 6 {2+7-1 \choose 7} + 4 {1+5-1 \choose 5}\right]$$
where $N(A)$ counts the number of collections with exactly two pieces of type one, $N(B)$ counts the number of collections with exactly two pieces of type two, $N(C)$ counts the number of collections with exactly two pieces of type three, $N(D)$ counts the number of collections with exactly two pieces of type four, and $N(U)$ counts all possible collections of eleven candies from four types with no restrictions.
However, I was told that the last term, $ 4 {1+5-1 \choose 5} = 4,$ should not be there. I do not understand why? In my solution, this is the case where the child has exactly two pieces of three types and then must take five pieces of the fourth type to complete the collection of eleven candies.

I agree that you need a term to cover the ${2,2,2,5}$ case.

It is possible that whoever said this intended to mean that one shouldn't just blindly throw binomial coefficients around when they are tedious and cumbersome to write and incredibly easily simplify... in this case $\binom{1+5-1}{5}=1$ could have been "invisible".  The $+4$ at the end, whether written as $4$ or as $4\times 1$ or... as $4\times \binom{\text{this is really}}{\text{long and unnecessary}}$ is still supposed to be there

The correct answer is 188, which is the coefficient $[x^{11}]$ of $(1+x+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+\cdots)^4$, where the missing $x^2$ indicates that no candy is taken exactly twice. To agree with that,  the term $4\binom{1+5-1}{5}$ is needed.
